# How can i use the Middleware "basic.auth" with a special group?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i created an api in Laravel 5.1 and now i will create a basic authentification. Here is my `routes.php`

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api/v1', 'middleware' => 'auth.basic'), function()
{
    Route::get('customer.getall', 'Api@getAllCustomer');
});
```

Now, everybody in the Users Table have access to the API. I have a special API User. He is in the Group **API_USERS**. Only Users in this group are supposed to use the Api.

How can i do this in Laravel 5.1?

Greetings

Comment: You may also use the namespace parameter within your group array to specify all controllers within that group as being in a given namespace:

Route::group(array('namespace' => 'Admin'), function()
{
    //
});

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider creating another middleware to handle the specific authentication that you would like to be implemented. This should give you an idea of creating one based on role which in your case is the group.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware#middleware-parameters